# MongoDB optimizing big aggregation queries

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

I have a collection of documents in MongoDB, representing some entity. For every entity there are some statistics data gathered on a daily basis. The statistics are put as a separate documents into different collections.

Entity collection schema:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  filterField1: String, //indexed
  filterField2: String, //indexed
}
```

Example schema of statistics collection:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  entityId: ObjectId, //indexed
  statisticsValue: Int32,
  date: Date //indexed
}
```

There is a dashboard that needs to display some aggregated statistics based on the gathered data over some time period e.x. average value, sum, count etc. The dashboard enables filtering in/out entities and applying different date ranges which makes precalculating those aggregated statistics impossible.

As for now, I've been using aggregation pipeline to:

- apply the filters on the entities collection (using match stage)
- make necessary lookups stages to acquire statistics for aggregation
- make grouping and aggregation (avg, sum, count, etc.)

Here is the pipeline:

```
db.getCollection('entities').aggregate([
    { $match: { $expr: { $and: [ 
        // ENTITIES FILTERS based on filterField1 and filterField2 fields 
    ] } } },
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'statistics',
        let: { entityId: '$_id' },
        pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $and: [
            { $eq: ["$entityId", "$$entityId"] },
            { $gte: [ "$date", new ISODate("2022-06-01T00:00:00Z") ] },
            { $lte: [ "$date", new ISODate("2022-06-01T23:59:59Z") ] },
        ] } } },
        as: 'stats_start_date_range',
     } },
     { $lookup: {
        from: 'statistics',
        let: { key: '$_key' },
        pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $and: [
            { $eq: ["$entityId", "$$entityId"] },
            { $gte: [ "$date", new ISODate("2022-06-31T00:00:00Z") ] },
            { $lte: [ "$date", new ISODate("2022-06-31T23:59:59Z") ] },
        ] } } },
        as: 'stats_end_date_range',
     } },
     { $addFields: 
       { 
         start_stats: { $first: "$stats_start_date_range" }, 
         end_stats: { $first: "$stats_end_date_range" } 
       }
     },
     {
       $group: {
         _id: null,
         avg_start: { $avg:  "$start_stats.statisticsValue" },
         avg_end: { $avg:  "$end_stats.statisticsValue" }
       }   
    }
])
```

In case of this query, the expected result is the average value of the `statisticsValue` field for the start and end date for every entity matching the filters.

I applied the index on the field used to left join collections in lookup stage. as well as on the date field used for getting statistics for a specific date.

The problem is that the query takes about 1 second for the max number of documents after the match stage (about 1000 documents). And I need to perform 4 such queries. The statistic collection contains 800k documents and the number is growing every day.

I was wondering, if I can do anything to make the query execution faster, I considered:

- time series collection
- reorganizing collections structure (don't know how)
- merging those 4 separate queries into 1, using facet stage

But I'm not sure if MongoDB is suitable data source for such operations and maybe I should consider another data source if I want to perform such queries.

Comment: Please provide some sample input data and expected result. Looks like, you don't need any data from `entities` collection, so you can aggregate only from `statistics`.  For sure, you don't need to run two `$lookup`, lookup only once for start and end range and split it later.

Comment: ... or if you need the `entities` collection to apply the filters in the `"$match"`, make sure to have an index on each of those fields, or perhaps even compound and/or multikey indexes.

Comment: When it comes to the match stage performance, it is acceptable. The lookup stage seems to be a problem.

Comment: Where are the indexes?

Comment: The schema do not match the query at all.

Comment: The schemas and query has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess, what you would like to get. An approach could be this one:

```
const entities = db.getCollection('entities').aggregate([
   { $match: { filterField1: "a" } }
]).toArray().map(x => x._id)

db.getCollection('statistics').aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         entityId: { $in: entities },
         date: {
            $gte: ISODate("2022-06-01T00:00:00Z"),
            $lte: ISODate("2022-06-31T23:59:59Z")
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $facet: {
         stats_start_date_range: [
            {
               $match: {
                  date: {
                     $gte: ISODate("2022-06-01T00:00:00Z"),
                     $lte: ISODate("2022-06-01T23:59:59Z")
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         stats_end_date_range: [
            {
               $match: {
                  date: {
                     $gte: ISODate("2022-06-31T00:00:00Z"),
                     $lte: ISODate("2022-06-31T23:59:59Z")
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      $addFields: {
         start_stats: { $first: "$stats_start_date_range" },
         end_stats: { $first: "$stats_end_date_range" }
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         avg_start: { $avg: "$start_stats.statisticsValue" },
         avg_end: { $avg: "$end_stats.statisticsValue" }
      }
   }
]);
```